# Need help in writing the grok pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Can anybody help me writing the grok pattern for the following log line

```
07-Aug-2017|00:35:08,748 DEBUG [hostname] [Some WebApp Name] [6.9] [127.0.0.1] [1277]
```

I am not able to find a way to accomodate '[' & ']' in the grok patterns.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any update on this? Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should match your pattern:

```
%{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR}\|%{TIME} %{LOGLEVEL} \[%{WORD} ] \[%{DATA}] \[%{NUMBER}] \[%{IP}] \[%{NUMBER}]
```

As you can see squared bracket are escaped with backslashes like this: `\[` and `\]`

You might want to add semantic to it like so:

```
%{MONTHDAY:day}-%{MONTH:month}-%{YEAR:year}\|%{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \[%{WORD:hostname} ] \[%{DATA:webapp}] \[%{NUMBER:somenumber}] \[%{IP:userip}] \[%{NUMBER:anothernumber}]
```

You can also test your grok patterns online e.g. [here](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match).